# Breaking Out Of Recursive Loop JS

Tags: javascript, recursion, ecmascript-6

```
deepSearchObject(obj) {
  let duplicateExists = false;

  Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {
    if(key === 'fieldCode') {
      let value = obj[key]
      if(this.fieldCodes.includes(value)) {
        duplicateExists = true;
        return;
      } else {
        this.fieldCodes.push(value);
      }
    }
    if (typeof obj[key] === 'object') {
            this.deepSearchObject(obj[key])
    }
  })

  console.log('RETURN VALUE', duplicateExists);
  return duplicateExists;
},
```

Ideally I want to return from deepSearchObject when a duplicate is found, no more reason to traverse the object, currently instead of returning on the last line, the code above will log out the return value of True and then continue to execute, why? I've broken out of the loop with the return, do I need something else to break out of recursion?

Comment: `return false;` to terminate the forEach, or throw an exception and put the logic in a try catch block.

Comment: same behavior with return false

Comment: Hmm, could have swore return false terminated forEach.  Looks like that's incorrect.

Comment: You cannot "break out of recursion". The most you can do is to `return`  a result to the caller. Then, when the recursive call returns something, you *also* need to break from the loop.

Comment: its correct it does, but the loop continues, is it running in a seperate recursive call on the call stack that hasn't been terminated?

Comment: @Taplar `return false` terminates `jQuery.each` afaik.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/vqnL9t6e/ @Bergi  yeah, that's what i was remembering.

Comment: From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach): `There is no way to stop or break a forEach() loop other than by throwing an exception. If you need such behavior, the forEach() method is the wrong tool.`

Comment: That's because you can't break out of a `forEach` loop and `return` doesn't work either. I'd consider using `for ..loop` or `for..of..loop` for this

Comment: guys this is not a for loop foreach loop issue

Comment: in the code above even though i break out of the foreach it still keeps running as if the other recursions are finishing

Comment: @AdamWeitzman - yes it is. `forEach` doesn't do what you expect it to do. Use a different loop construct that will do what you want it to do.

Comment: @Bergi closed the question so i cant edit it, i added return false and the same behavior is happening

Comment: Related to all that.  Shouldn't the logic be `duplicateExists = this.deepSearchObject(obj[key])` since each call gets it's own version of the variable?

Comment: ooo @Taplar i think you're onto it there

Comment: @AdamWeitzman You still can [edit] the question. But what you really need to change is the `Object.keys().forEach` into a `for in`, just adding `return false` does not help - see the duplicate for more explanation of that issue.

Comment: im not seeing the change but will keep looking

Comment: changing to for in has the same behavior looks like